# How to get in which store did the specific product get the most benefit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, here are my tables:

**Sales**

| id | product_code | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4536 | 1 |
| 2 | 4674 | 2 |

**Products**

| product_code | product_name | price | real_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4536 | Red bull energy drink 300 ml | 3,68 | 2,88 |
| 4674 | Mac coffee 25 gr | 2,59 | 2,10 |

**Stores**

| store_id | store_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first |
| 2 | second |

*I need to find in which store the product 'red bull' got the most benefit. Benefit is considered as price-real_price. Quantity is considered as repetition of product_code in sales table.*

Expected output:

| product_name | benefit | store_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red bull energy drink 300 ml | 4536,4 | second |

Here is what I tried:

```
select 
   products.product_name, (sum( price-real_price)*count(sales.product_code)) as benefit from products
join sales on sales.store_id = stores.store_id
where products.product_name like '%red bull%'
group by products.product_name
```

But it does not give me the output I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the store in question by grouping by `store_id` and ordering by the benefit.

```
select top(1)
   sales.store_id, sum(price-real_price)*count(sales.product_code) as benefit 
from products
join sales on sales.product_code = products.product_code
where products.product_name like '%red bull%'
group by sales.store_id
order by sum(price-real_price)*count(sales.product_code) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a query like below will help.
Note that I have used [dense rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get all stores which have same benefit in case of ties. Also it neatly allows the logic to be changed later.

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3a96be0172b33209509dbb67eaeef47)

```
; with benefitperstore as 
(
select 
s.store_name,
P.product_name, 
count(1) * (P.price - P.real_price) as benefit
from Sales X join Stores s 
   on X.Store_id=s.Store_id
join Products P 
   on P.product_code=X.product_code
where product_name like '%red bull%'
group by s.store_name,P.price- P.real_price,P.product_name
)
, mostBenefit as
(
select *, 
dense_rank() over (order by benefit desc) as rn 
from benefitperstore 
)

select 
product_name,
benefit,
store_name
from mostBenefit 
where rn=1
```